# Want to delete old products on my product pages

Tags: product

I need to put new products on magento product pages and remove old ones. I have tried that on admin page but the old products don't delete when I try to.

Comment: you want to delete all product's

Comment: is there a reason you need to completely delete them? if not you could just set their status to Disabled

Comment: No I want to delete the old ones only .But if there is no way I can also delete all the products and upload the new ones again.

Comment: The reason I want to delete them is they have black background and the new products have a white background which matches the website

Comment: I want to only delete the products not the entire page.If I set the status to disable it will hide the entire page

Comment: Tell us how make the difference the old with the news?
They have different type sku's ?
And then we tells you how make a script to delete only those ones.

Comment: Please add more details to the question about what you are trying to achieve. Your question suggests that you want to delete the product itself, although your comments suggest that you only want to replace the product images. There is a difference between both.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you only want to delete the product images? If yes, go to the images tab for the product. Next to product image tick the "remove" box and save. Image should be gone. Use browse files and upload files to add new images with white background only.

Answer (score 1):

The better way will be mass uploading. Collect all images in a folder and make a csv file with sku and  related image path.
Upload image in `media/import` folder and then import the csv file in `System > Import/Export > Import`
You can get tutorials for mass uploading products in magento.
Images will be replaced by this method.